# Pause button of audio control is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the audio tag with file source. File is located on server. On click of play icon in audio control, tone is played but if clicked on pause button nothing happens. It continues to play the tone and once it is finished playing, if you again try to click on play button it wont play.

```
<label style="color:wheat">Ringtone file:</label>
<audio controls="controls">
 <source src="/prWsdsfTonftr~99?q=1573290924">
</audio>
```

Comment: which version of firefox ?

Comment: please specify the version of firefox and also check the console for any errors or warnings!

Comment: check this, if this is working or not in your browser...?? https://plnkr.co/edit/UuH3BcQDgWMgLySJ95hQ?p=preview

Comment: Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: I checked console but there are no errors or warnings.

Comment: Try add the `type` attribute to your `<source>` tag. Also, which doctype did you  declare? In HTML you can simply write `<audio controls>`, while in XHTML you write (as you did) `<audio controls="controls">`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio and https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_audio_controls.asp

Comment: I checked above url in firefox, it is working fine.

Comment: I have used <!DOCTYPE html>, also audio tag is proper.

Comment: I suspect my issue is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863917/html5-audio-mp3-not-working-in-firefox